# Bash: Replace part of string with wildcard in search pattern

Tags: bash

I have working script that looks for errors in log files :

```
CONFIGFILE=testfmc.ini
log=log1.log
res=0
while read line ;
    do
    echo "$line"
    if [[ "$line" == PAT[0-9][0-9]* ]] ; then
    echo "line --$line--"
    patnum=$(echo "$line" | awk -F= '{print $1}');
    pattern=$(echo "$line" | awk -F= '{print $2}');
    echo "$patnum   ---   $pattern";
    res=$(fgrep -c "$pattern" $log );
        if [[ "$res" -gt 0 ]] ; then 
        echo "Error in log files $res";
        fi
    echo "End of IF";
fi
echo  $res;
done < $CONFIGFILE
```

testfmc.ini is the file with the patterns :

```
PAT01=java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
PAT02=javax.mail.StoreClosedException: failed to create new store connection
PAT03=javax.mail.MessagingException: ServerName NO Server Unavailable
PAT04=javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE Connection is closed
```

The problem is that in PAT03 there is a Server name and this error may show up with several Server names. How can i replace the ServerName in the pattern with WILDCARD. I have tried with * or * or "*" and several more options , but nothing works.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with this code? An English-language description would be easier to work with.

Comment: If the "ServerName" is never meaningful (i.e. you don't want to catch only things that can be server names, nor will extract it after match), you should really modify the pattern file

Comment: By the way -- all the `awk -F=` is silly. Much more efficient to use `while IFS="=" read -r patnum pattern` to read directly into the variables you want.

Comment: If your real question is how to match each line of a file against a list of glob-style patterns given in another file, **ask that question explicitly**; don't ask how to "replace part of a string with a wildcard", if that's not actually what you want to do (and you aren't sure that being able to do it will solve your real problem).

Comment: (Also, what's the point of the `PAT01=` / `PAT02=` type names? Why not just put the patterns one to a line?)

Comment: It will be easier to track with PAT* for the rest of the script i dint post.

Comment: If the goal is for your output to include that PAT* identifier to indicate which patterns were matched (or such), then when you ask a question that's properly on the topic, I'd suggest specifying that output well enough to make the reason for it being included in the input clear. (The most obvious, performant implementation would build a single regex covering all the possible patterns, and scan for it in one pass).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in ini file replace:

`PAT03=javax.mail.MessagingException: ServerName NO Server Unavailable`

with

`PAT03=javax.mail.MessagingException: .* NO Server Unavailable`

in script replace:

`res=$(fgrep -c "$pattern" $log );`

with:

`res=$(grep -E "$pattern" $log );`

the script is not well optimized but works so :) good luck

Comment: Thanks , may be the only combination i did not try was with .*  
Works perfectly now.

Comment: Giving him what he needs, and not what he asked for? How will we ever get people to ask good questions if we do that? :)

Comment: (...more seriously, this means that if we have someone who **actually** wants to know how to replace part of a string with a wildcard, they'd be finding this question -- about something different -- and its accepted answer -- also about something different -- rather than what they actually need).

Answer (score 2):

The desired operation (replacing part of a string with a wildcard) is trivially done with a parameter expansion:

```
s='PAT03=javax.mail.MessagingException: ServerName NO Server Unavailable'
s2="${s//ServerName/'*'}"
echo "$s2"
```

*(There are other issues with your script as a whole -- `fgrep` matches literal strings, not regular expressions or glob-style patterns, and the other grep variants use regexes while your patterns here are glob-style -- but if your intended question's scope expands beyond what's in the title, you should be asking a new question directly on point rather than slipping what you actually want to know into the details of a different question entirely).*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use fgrep to do that. I thought `fgrep` only looks for strings, not patterns.

Perhaps use normal `grep` or `egrep`, and put the pattern as `.*` rather than `*`.

PS @Charles suggestion regarding `IFS` is great.

Comment: well you can't have your cake and eat it! Perhaps you need `\*` in PAT04. Your'e calling them "patterns", so I would not expect them to be literals -- I would expect things like `*` to be quoted.